# Scroll to bottom of page on click, using JavaScript, NOT JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, scroll

I have a pop-up and when the user clicks "continue", it should scroll to the bottom of the window if a certain condition is true. I am working in type script and cannot use any jQuery, so this needs to be done using javascript and it doesn't need to be a smooth scroll either. Here is my html:

```
<ion-content class="pc-nativeScannerPage">

  <p *ngIf="isPackagingSuggested">
    SELECT new packaging and SELECT reason for change.
  </p>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row #packagingOptionsRow>
      <ion-col>
        <div class="boxItem" (click)="selectPackaging(packaging.packagingId)" [class.active]="data.inputs.selectedPackagingIds.indexOf(packaging.packagingId) !== -1">
          <p>
            <span *ngIf="language === 'EN'">{{ packaging.packagingTitle }}</span>
            <span *ngIf="!packaging.shipInExistingBox">{{ packaging.width }} x {{ packaging.height }} x {{ packaging.depth }}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-row *ngIf="isPackagingSuggested">
    <ion-col *ngFor="let reason of data.inputs.changeReasons">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label></ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="reason.selected" (ionChange)="onChangeReason(reason)"></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>  
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-right>
      <span *ngIf="error" class="pc-continue-error">{{ error | translate }}</span>
      <button (click)="continue()" class="pc-primary" ion-button>{{ 'BUTTON_CONTINUE' | translate }}</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

It is when the user clicks the button with the continue() function that I would like it to scroll to the bottom of the page. Below is my JS:

```
  continue() {
    if (!this.data.inputs.selectedPackagingIds.length) {
      this.error = 'Please select new packaging.'; 
    } else if (this.isPackagingSuggested && !this.data.inputs.changeReasons.filter(r => { return r.selected }).length) {
      window.scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".pc-nativeScannerPage").scrollHeight);
      this.error = 'Please select change reason.'; 
    } else {
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(LabelPrintTab, { data: this.data });
    }
  }
```

As you can see, I have tried to use scrollTO() but this does not work, and I've read it doesn't work on a lot of browsers, so I am trying to find a solution that will work across all browser. 
I am very new at this, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) instead

Comment: @RandyCasburn how?

Comment: @RandyCasburn perhaps you missed the part where i said i was very new to this. i read the documentation and i am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: That's why I provided the solution in the answer below. I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [cross browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview) solution below represents your use case.

1. User interaction to start the process (click red box)
2. Click a control in a pop-up
3. Scroll the page to some content

Without everything else, all it takes is to call:

```
document.getElementById('SOMEIDHERE').scrollIntoView();
```

That single statement will place the element with id SOMEIDHERE into the view port.

NOTE: if that element is at the bottom of the page (with no content below it), it will appear at the bottom of the page.

For further detail into how you can use `.scrollIntoView` *and actually try this out on your own*, please refer to the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

```js
document.getElementById('top').addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (window.confirm("Click OK to scroll the bottom element into view")) {
    document.getElementById('bottom').scrollIntoView();
  }
});
```

```css
#top {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.spacer {
  height: 1000px;
}

#bottom {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">CLICK THIS RED BOX</div>
<div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="bottom">This is in the center of the page - scroll in either direction</div>
<div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
```